# KineticJS change property after object creation (NOOB)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, properties, kineticjs

Hello guys I am a noob in KineticJS and I want to know how to change property values. For example for a rectangle after its creation:

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x: 239,
          y: 75,
          width: 100,
          height: 50,
          fill: "#00D2FF",
          stroke: "black",
          strokeWidth: 4
        });
```

How would I do something like this:

```
rect.NewProperty({
      x: 100,
      y: 30,
      width: 100,
      height: 50,
      fill: "#cccccc",
    });
```

and leave the other properties the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x: 239,
          y: 75,
          width: 100,
          height: 50,
          fill: "#00D2FF",
          stroke: "black",
          strokeWidth: 4
        });

rect.setFill("#D200FF");
rect.setStrokeWidth(1);
```

Comment: thanks for answer. So as I mentioned I must add word "set" and everything will be same? for example .setWidth , .setStroke, setHeight , .setX, setY ...

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the info..

i also tried

```
rect.setWidth(100);
```

and

```
rect.setHeight(100);
```

it works :)